# allow anonymous to create page

Tags: drupal-6

I have set permission to allow anonymous user to create page.
but when the anonymous user submmited the page, drupal 6 responded "page not found".

i have checked drupal backend, there was no page created.

so my question is, which permisson option i have to set to allow 
anonymous user to create a page.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Anonymous users can create content if you give them permissions in the back end. Go to yoursite.com/admin/user/permissions and make scroll down to the "Node Module". Make sure you have "access content" and any relevant "create **foo** content" boxes checked (where **foo** is the content type you want them to be able to create) for anonymous users.

This will grant anonymous users permission to create content of type **foo**, and view any content created.

Your "Access Denied" problem may be caused by anonymous users being able to create content, but not access it. This would be the case if you have granted "create **foo** content" permissions to the anonymous user, but have not given them "access content" permissions. Can you see the content while you are logged in as an admin?

Comment: i have granted "access content" to anonymouse user.

Comment: i have create a listing content type, granted anonymouse user create listing content, edit listing content and access content permission.

Comment: also, turned on editing , view permission for all fields in the listing content type.

Comment: Not sure what else to tell you then. Creating content is pretty straightforward in Drupal, so if you cannot do that then maybe there is something wrong with your installation. What platform are you running it on? Also, have you seen if an anonymous user can create one of the predefined content types, like a page or a story? It might be a problem with your content type. Another thing to check: see if the admin can create content.

Comment: my installation probably got some thing wrong, i have tried on a different machine, and successed.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem right now and it drove me crazy! After a bit researching I did a try rebuilding permissions at /admin/content/node-settings after remembering that this solved such issues related to node access for me before.

I am a senior developer and Drupal developer for about 4 years and until now I don't know why this happens. Who knows a clarification to all of this please please share..

http://drupal.org/user/642644

Answer (score 0):

Not super familiar with the tech you're using but can a registered user create a page? If not, the problem probably is because of something else. :)

Comment: i have create a content_admin account, and assinged permission to the account. after login , the account can create page content, looks like some thing did not turned on for anonymouse user